# Phabricator hosted repository returning error 500 on clone

Tags: git, apache, phabricator

I have a web server running Phabricator and hosted repositories and will intermittently get:

```
The requested URL returned error: 500
```

When issuing various git commands (today specifically git clone over http).

There is nothing in the apache error log, I have my VCS password established and have previously had successful clones/pushes to this instance of phabricator. Im unsure what happens overnight to make it behave this way =/

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Adding the line to /etc/sudoers in the format: "www-user ALL=(daemon-user) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /path/to/git-http-backend, /path/to/hg" per the documentation worked but it would be annoying to do this every day.

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but, to receive an help you should share at least the error log from your PHP-FPM (if you have that) and not just your apache/nginx error log. Note that I cannot share an example log path for PHP-FPM, since it's heavily change between Linux distributions. So feel free to also share that information (your distro).